# Trying to create QueryOver for many to many relationship with projections

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, queryover, nhibernate-projections

I have two tables (Orders, Transactions) and a TransactionsOrders lookup table that just retains an OrderId and TransactionsId columns.

There can be multiple transactions for an order if a transaction failed (n) times. And the Order object doesn't have any knowledge of the transactions.

I believe I will need to use projections as I will need to return all the order properties as well as two properties from the Transactions table (Amount and TransactionDate) if a *successful* transaction record exists for that order.  Below is the SQL that will generate the correct output.

```
   SELECT o.*, ct.TransactionDate, ct.Amount from Orders o
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM CreditTransactionsOrders cto
          INNER JOIN CreditTransactions ct 
      ON ct.Id = cto.CreditTransactionId
      WHERE ct.Successful = 1) as ct 
   ON o.Id = ct.OrderId
```

I have attempted to try creating this QueryOver and projecting the properties I need from the Order object and Transaction object but can't convert this SQL query properly.

The end results is that I need to return ALL orders, and I need to return the Amount and Date from the Transaction object IF a successful one exists for that Order.  I am not really sure if I have to use aliases, but so far all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Do you map your order-transaction as mant-to-many or you have mapped it with additional entity?

Comment: A transactions collection of Orders are mapped many to many.  Orders as mentioned has no knowledge of transactions.

Comment: Could you please provide your classes and mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to rewrite your SQL to more NHibernate friendly state:

```
SELECT o.*, ct.TransactionDate, ct.Amount from Orders o
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CreditTransactionsOrders cto 
    ON o.Id = cto.OrderId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CreditTransactions ct 
    ON ct.Id = cto.CreditTransactionId AND ct.Successful = 1
```

This SQL will produce the same results as your original query.

In NHibernate additional criteria for join could be translated as `with` statement.

So you could use overload accepting `withClause` argument. So, assuming you have Orders and CreditTransactions mapped as many-to-many. You should get following QueryOver.

```
Order o = null;
CreditTransaction ct = null;

var orders = session.QueryOver(() => o)
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Transactions, () => ct, () => ct.Successful == 1)
    .List<Order>();
```

**UPDATE**

As you have no reference from `Order` to `Transaction`, you should revert the join, so you could use right join to achieve this.

```
Order o = null;
CreditTransaction ct = null;

var orders = session.QueryOver(() => ct)
    .Right.JoinAlias(x => x.Orders, () => o, () => ct.Successful == 1)
    .Select(
        x => x.TransactionDate,
        x => x.Amount,
        x => o.Id // other Order fields
    ).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TransactionsDto>())
    .List<TransactionsDto>();
```

`TransactionsDto` class should contain all selected fields.

Comment: Isn't this just going to return all orders (possibly) and the orders from successfully transactions, but not any properties from the transaction object as mentioned needed (Amount, TransactionDate)?

Comment: No, it returns all orders and only successful transactions. And it will write result to Order graph, so each order will have initialized Transactions collection with only seccessful transactions. You could do a custom projection to fetch plain structures.

Comment: No, actually, you are referencing Transactions off of an Order which as I mentioned in the question - an Order doesn't have any knowledge of Transactions.  Only Transactions know about Orders.  So Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Transaction would not work.  However, I have found that it is almost required to add the mapping to the Order object to be able to have a manyToMany of Transactions so that a query could be written (at least easier).  The intent of the question was to find out how if I didn't have the relationship between order -> transaction.

Comment: @pghtech I've got your intentions, but unfortunately have no time to complete the challenge

Comment: Updated the answer. Sorry for so late reply